# Optimizely Episerver CMS - unable to upload SVG icons, "parameter is not valid"

Tags: c#, svg, episerver, optimizely

I wish to upload SVG-icons to my blocks / pages in Episerver. However, I get the error "parameter not valid" no matter what type of svg I attempt to upload. PNGs work fine.

```
    [MediaDescriptor(ExtensionString = "svg")]
    public class SvgIcon : MediaData
    {
        public override Blob Thumbnail
        {
            get { return BinaryData;  }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the class based on this article that ive tried to use:
https://mariajemaria.net/another-failed-svg-upload

Any suggestion as to how to potentially ignore these "parameters"?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you're missing a `ContentType` attribute?

I usually do something like the following:

```
[ContentType(DisplayName = "SVG Image", GUID = "42b1b1b3-450f-4c29-93f7-f98fdfb6fbb1")]
[MediaDescriptor(ExtensionString = "svg")]
public class SvgImageData : ImageData
{
    public override Blob Thumbnail
    {
        get { return BinaryData; }
    }
}
```

The `GUID` property can obviously be any valid GUID, but it's good practice to always include one.